# PHP code input data {a: Item1|item2|item3 } to Format into HTML list

Tags: php, list, explode

I am developing a script to format the data :

Change them if needed (your doctor will help you with this):{1:Your chair|Your pillow|{I:Your chair 1|Your pillow 2|Your mattress 3|Your shoes 4}|Your shoes} and i want everything inside {} to be as new list with the type stated inside braces {a: }

prefered seperator is |

PHP Code :

```
function processforsublist($str)
{
    $start = strpos($str, '{');
    $format = substr($str, $start+1 , 1);
    $end = strpos($str, '}');
    if($start!==false && $end!==false)
    {
    $cut = substr($str, $start, ($end-$start)+1);
    $class  = '';
    switch ($format) {
        case '1':
            $class = 'list_number';
            break;
        case 'a':
            $class = 'list_alpha_small';
            break;
        case 'A':
            $class = 'list_alpha_caps';
            break;
        case 'i':
            $class = 'list_roman_small';
            break;
        case 'I':
            $class = 'list_roman_caps';
            break;

        default:
            $class = 'list_number';
            break;
    }
    $cutn = str_replace('{', '', $cut);
    $cutn = str_replace('}', '', $cutn);
    $cutn = str_replace($format.":", '', $cutn);

    //echo $cutn;

    $exploded = explode('|', $cutn);

    $lis = '';
    foreach ($exploded as $value) {
        if(strpos($str, '{')!==false)
        $lis .= "<li>".processforsublist($value)."</li>";
        else
        $lis .= "<li>".trim($value)."</li>";    
    }


    $newstr = "<ol class='$class'>$lis</ol>";

    echo $str."<hr/>".$cut."<hr/>".$newstr."<hr/>";

    $istr = str_replace($cut, $newstr, $str);   


    return $istr;
    }
    else {
        return $str;
    }       
}

echo processforsublist('Change them if needed (your doctor will help you with this):{1:Your chair|Your pillow|{I:Your chair 1|Your pillow 2|Your mattress 3|Your shoes 4}|Your shoes}');
```

Current Output :

```
Change them if needed (your doctor will help you with this):
    1.Your chair
    2.Your pillow
    3.Your chair 1
    4.Your pillow 2
    5.Your mattress 3
    6.Your shoes 4
|Your shoes}
```

Required Output:

```
Change them if needed (your doctor will help you with this):
    1.Your chair
    2.Your pillow
        I.Your chair 1
        II.Your pillow 2
        III.Your mattress 3
        IV.Your shoes 4
    3.Your shoes
```

Comment: Alrighty. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Well .. solution would be writing some code. Have you tried hiring a developer? Because what you have there are project requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done too much work there.
Following seems enough for your requirements.

```
$str="{1:Your chair|Your pillow|{I:Your chair 1|Your pillow 2|Your mattress 3|Your shoes 4}|Your shoes}";
$str=str_replace("{1:","<ol type=1><li>",$str);
$str=str_replace("{a:","<ol type=a><li>",$str);
$str=str_replace("{A:","<ol type=A><li>",$str);
$str=str_replace("{i:","<ol type=i><li>",$str);
$str=str_replace("{I:","<ol type=I><li>",$str);
$str=str_replace("}","</li></ol>",$str);
$str=str_replace("|","</li><li>",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it sounds like JSON strings might be a better option. Look into `json_encode` and `json_decode`. It'll make your life a million times better.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are couple of things  you need to change.
just a brief points here:

1. try  `$end = strrpos($str, '}');` in place of  `$end = strpos($str, '}');` as in the current code it searches for the first occurrence of } so the string you have will be searched as first occurrence of { and first occurrence of } which is wrong as it will have any number of '{' in between.
2. `$cutn = str_replace('{', '', $cut);
   $cutn = str_replace('}', '', $cutn);` This replaces all the occurrences

try `$cutn = preg_replace('/{/', '', $cut,1);
    $cutn =substr_replace($cutn,'', strrpos($cutn, '}'), 1);`

1. `$exploded = explode('|', $cutn);` this will give you array of everything but not sub array as you need it for displaying the roman numbers. so you need to change that.

Hope this helps